# How to pair bluetooth using nfc

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

I have currently created a chatting app which uses Bluetooth to send a message to and fro. Now I want to pair Bluetooth of two Android devices with NFC. I have searched GitHub and google and I found no solution. I checked NFC forum, they indeed provide documentation for pairing Bluetooth using NFC but it is limited to paid members(I think). But searching in StackOverflow I found some question asking about pairing Bluetooth using NFC. I wonder from where other got this much information to start. I am quite new at this. I just need to know where to start and know whether it is possible to do without paying NFC forum. (It is just for college project purpose only!!!!!!)

Thanking in Advance

Answer (score 2):

If it was possible to send NdefMessages back and forth with Android devices, you could potentially initiate the NFC interaction between the devices using the [Bluetooth Secure Simple Pairing Using NFC](https://nfc-forum.org/our-work/specifications-and-application-documents/application-documents/) protocol.

I think this is not possible so you may need to use Host Card Emulation (HCE) on a device and emulate a static NFC tag with a Handover Selector Record and potentially disregard having the back and forth NDEF messages. The other device would operate in reader mode and read the static NFC (emulated) tag and connect using the information in the Alternate Carrier Record payload. See the Static Handover section in the above link for more details.

The first device emulates a NdefMessage with a Handover Selector Record

```
TNF: Well-Known Type
RTD: Handover Selector ('Hs')
```

followed by a number of Alternate Carrier Records

```
TNF: Well-Known Type
RTD: Alternative Carrier ('ac')
```

The Alternate Carrier Record indicates the Bluetooth MAC address in it's payload.

[A helpful source.](https://books.google.ie/books?id=ScuYAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=handover%20select%20message%20android&source=bl&ots=CKfK92JBHp&sig=GV7H3JIGPjA5XCJCKEWHZXQ1vOw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimxoykhpLcAhUrCMAKHZyEBmkQ6AEIVzAF#v=onepage&q=handover%20select%20message%20android&f=false)

[A helpful forum to ask similar NFC related questions.](https://flomio.com/forums/forum/ask-the-flomies/)